# Salvar tempo do cronômetro ao reiniciar página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um cronômetro regressivo em JavaScript que após 3 dias ele reinicia a contagem, porém gostaria de saber como posso fazer para a contagem não reiniciar ao recarregar a página.

```
let time = new Date();
let finalDate = new Date();
finalDate.setDate(time.getDate()+3);

setInterval(function() {
    time = new Date();
    finalDate = new Date();
    finalDate.setDate(time.getDate()+3);
    console.log('Funcionou')
}, 259200000)

let now, timeLeft, timeString;

let timer = setInterval(function() {
    now = Date.now();
    dateDiff = finalDate - now;
    timeLeft = new Date(dateDiff);
    
    timeString = timeLeft.toLocaleTimeString (
    'pt-BR', 
        {   
            hour12: false, 
            minute: '2-digit', 
            second: '2-digit', 
            hour: '2-digit', 
            day: '2-digit', 
            timeZone: 'GMT'
        }
    )

    $('.timer .count-timer .days').text(timeString.split(':')[0].split(" ")[0]);
    $('.timer .count-timer .hours').text(timeString.split(':')[0].split(" ")[1]);
    $('.timer .count-timer .minutes').text(timeString.split(':')[1]);
    $('.timer .count-timer .seconds').text(timeString.split(':')[2]);
}, 1000)
```

Comment: por favor, coloque mais detalhes. Qual é a variável que deseja salvar?

Comment: Tentou salvar o `finalDate` em um `localStorage`, por exemplo, e consultar ele toda vez que a página for recarregada? Fiquei confuso no uso do `setInterval`

Comment: Muito legal a sua pergunta! :-D Vou acompanhar aqui para ver o que a galera vai responder ;-) Faz mais de 100 anos que não mexo com web e estou meio enferrujado. Se você criar um cookie para armazenar a data e ler quando o usuário voltar a carregar a página não funciona?

Comment: Gostaria de salvar o finalDate

Comment: Essa solução do localStorage eu até pensei em fazer, mas quando um novo usuário acessar a página o cronômetro será reiniciado novamente não ? Pq o localStorage não vai existir

Comment: @LuizFelipedaSilva aí vc vai precisar de um backend, pode usar o google firebase caso não queira fazer um do 0

Answer (score 2):

Para salvar e ler a data localmente você pode usar o `localStorage`:
Salvando:
`localStorage.setItem('data', finalDate.toString())`
Lendo:
`finalDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem('data'))`
Caso `localStorage.getItem('data')` for `null`, você inicia `finalDate` normalmente.

Porém pelo que entendi, você quer salvar para todos usuários. Aí você irá precisar de um back-end para salvar e ler a data a partir do servidor. Você não precisa criar um back-end apenas para isso, você pode usar soluções gratuitas existentes como o [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).